# I want to add multiple item to cart now getting only one item and next item replaced with old one

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I'm working on E-Com web and trying to add multiple item to cart using list whenever user click on add to cart button.
but the thing is i'm able to add only current item and lost old once.
I'm using session to store, not storing in database right now.
So Kindly help me out with this.

```
//** Here is what i tried**
//Defined in class//
public class ItemCart
{
    public class ItemList
    {
        public List<ItemDet> ListItems { get; set; }
    }

    public class ItemDet
    {

        public string ItemNo { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public string Size { get; set; }
        public string Quantity { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
        public string Amount { get; set; }

    }
}

protected void BtnCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<ItemCart.ItemDet> l;
    List<ItemCart.ItemList> commObj = new List<ItemCart.ItemList>();
    int rowIndex = 0;
    string Quantity = Request.Form["quantity"];
    string lblSalePrc = lblSalePrice.Text;
    string Price = lblSalePrc.ToString();
    string p = Price.Remove(0, 9);
    string Amount = Request.Form[txtAmount.UniqueID];
    l = new List<ItemCart.ItemDet>();
    ItemCart.ItemDet item = new ItemCart.ItemDet
    {
        ItemNo = "0",
        ItemName = h3.InnerText,
        Quantity = Quantity,
        Price = p,
        Amount = Amount,
        Size = "xl"
    };
    l.Add(item);
    ItemCart.ItemList Common = new ItemCart.ItemList
    {
        ListItems = l
    };

    commObj.Add(Common);
    rowIndex += 1;
    Session["OdList"] = l;
    Response.Redirect("Cart.aspx");
}
//Cart.aspx
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<ItemCart.ItemDet> list = (List<ItemCart.ItemDet>)Session["OdList"];
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGridview(1);
    }
}
protected void BindGridview(int count)
{
    List<ItemCart.ItemDet> list = (List<ItemCart.ItemDet>)Session["OdList"];
    ListtoDataTable lsttodt = new ListtoDataTable();
    DataTable dt2 = lsttodt.ToDataTable(list);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("ItemNo", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("ItemName", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Size", typeof(string));

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["ItemNo"] = string.Empty;
        dr["ItemName"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Quantity"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Price"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Amount"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Size"] = string.Empty;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    }
    dt = dt2;
    gvDetails.DataSource = dt;
    gvDetails.DataBind();
    for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        TextBox ItemNo = (TextBox)gvDetails.Rows[i].FindControl("ItemNo");
        TextBox ItemName = (TextBox)gvDetails.Rows[i].FindControl("ItemName");
        TextBox Quantity = (TextBox)gvDetails.Rows[i].FindControl("Quantity");
        TextBox Price = (TextBox)gvDetails.Rows[i].FindControl("Price");
        TextBox Amount = (TextBox)gvDetails.Rows[i].FindControl("Amount");
        TextBox Size = (TextBox)gvDetails.Rows[i].FindControl("Size");
        ItemNo.Text = dt.Rows[i]["ItemNo"].ToString();
        ItemName.Text = dt.Rows[i]["ItemName"].ToString();
        Quantity.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Quantity"].ToString();
        Price.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Price"].ToString();
        Amount.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Amount"].ToString();
        Size.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Size"].ToString();
    }
}
```

But Next time when i add value the previous one got cleared..
Kindly suggest me suitable way.

Comment: Store the data in the session state.

Comment: I have stored but next time when i add new item then it got replaced with new one @Patrick

Comment: And also when i'm creating object of ItemDet class then list get clear.

Comment: Then reuse the existing list.

Comment: Can you please show me some example or bunch of code.. That would be appreciated

Comment: There is in the duplicates.

Comment: Let me go through it then @Patrick Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158075/discussion-between-dhawal-and-patrick-hofman).